# How do I separate tags in a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently using .split to try to split a string into different 'tags'.

```js
let text = "@yusra is cool @zain @chris is cool";
const myArray = text.split("@");
console.log(myArray);
```

The code above gives this output:

```
Array ["", "yusra is cool ", "zain ", "chris is cool"]
```

the expected output is:

```
Array ["yusra", "zain ", "chris"]
```

How do I modify this to make it do what I want.

Comment: Either use a regex to get everything between an @ and the next space. Or split on the spaces, filter out all strings not starting with an @ and finally remove the @ from the names.

Comment: 1. split by words, 2.check if the word begins with @, 3. if yes remove @ and add it to myArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using split you can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to find the tags via a regex.

```js
let text = "@yusra is cool @zain @chris is cool";
const myArray = text.match(/@\w+/g);
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```js
let text = "@yusra is cool @zain @chris is cool";
const myArray = text.split(" ").filter(s => s.startsWith("@")).map(s => s.substring(1));
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex. Here we match `@` and then one or more lowercase letters between "a" and "z".

```js
const text = "@yusra is cool @zain @chris is cool @bob";
console.log(text.match(/@[a-z]+/g));
```

Answer (score 1):

Chain together what you need to complete the task.  Splitting on space seems to be a better option, then filter only those that have '@' and mapping to remove the '@'.

```js
let text = "@yusra is cool @zain @chris is cool";
const myArray = text.split(' ').filter(s => s.startsWith('@')).map(s => s.slice(1))
console.log(myArray);
```